# Speaker and player on same 5V charger crackles but not with two separate chargers

Tags: power-supply, audio, dc, noise

I am using a Samsung mobile phone connected to an external speaker (connected via a standard audio cable with jack connectors).

Audio is playing fine when I use two Samsung-branded 5V-DC chargers, where each device is powered by its own separate charger.

The problem is when I connect both the phone and the speaker to the same shared charger. I do not use any kind of USB hub — I've soldered the wires together without any inserted components.

Specifically, when audio is playing I can hear (not very loud) random "electronic" crackles. They are not any kind of periodic hiss, noise or hum but really like "random singing". Both chargers are always connected to the same wall socket.

My question is: is there any kind of component or action I can add/take to get rid of the audio crackles?

I've tried different brands of charger (Samsung, Google) but the problem was the same.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Is what you're calling a power supply actually a charger? Chargers do just output smooth and continuous DC. By the way, please edit such extra info' into your question by changing the original text, without adding 'edit' or unnecessary emphasis. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I tried chargers from Samsung and Google. Two separate Samsung chargers and one shared Samsung charger and then also a shared Google charger. The brand did not matter.

Comment: And by the way, TonyM, thanks for removing all the bold keyword styling from my post. It's all more clear now. Because why should the keywords "question", and "problem" be in bold, right?

Comment: Correct: why. The shouting and over-emphasis is gone as words work perfectly well by themselves. I also fixed the bad grammar. I then edited the new information into your question that you were asked to do, so that readers don't have to piece together the real question. You haven't got 'power supplies', you've got chargers. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Please take the tour if you haven't already.

Comment: Correction to my very first comment, should have said: chargers do not just output smooth and continuous DC.